# Use Facebook Connect using Lua?

Tags: facebook, lua

I am a beginner in Lua and was trying to implement Facebook connect api using Lua. I searched online and found out that Corona SDK provides this but I am not allowed to purchase any SDK and use Lua.
   Can anyone suggest any open source SDK or any other way that I can implement facebook connect api using Lua?

Comment: @nicol do you think there are examples out already??

Comment: I don't have an answer for you; I was simply correcting your usage of Lua (it's not LUA. It's not an acronym; it's a proper name).

Comment: Oh ok. Well thanks for your correction

Comment: I don't personally see cause for either a down vote or a vote to close. The question is narrow in scope, and is seeking guidance for where to start without being a typical "send me teh codez" type question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not already be a wrapping of the FB API in Lua. That said, it should not be difficult to do.

The [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) module supplies support for HTTP requests. You would use it to request the individual URLs that make up the API calls. Those requests will return data in JSON format that you will need to parse in order to use.

To parse JSON easily in Lua, you will want to find a suitable wrapper for a JSON parser. A quick search shows that there are a fair number of choices out there. A popular one appears to be [JSON4Lua](http://json.luaforge.net/).

[Here](http://postneo.com/2006/10/05/web-services-with-json-and-lua) is an article that includes a worked example for accessing a particular JSON-based API from Yahoo! based on both LuaSocket and JSON4Lua. The sample code looks like:

```
-- Client for the Yahoo Traffic API (http://developer.yahoo.com/traffic/rest/V1/index.html)
-- using JSON and Lua
-- Matt Croydon (matt@ooiio.com) http://postneo.com

http = require("socket.http") -- http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~diego/professional/luasocket/
json = require("json") -- http://json.luaforge.net/

-- Retrieve traffic information for Kansas City, MO
r, c, h = http.request("http://local.yahooapis.com/MapsService/V1/trafficData?appid=LuaDemo&city=Kansas+City&state=MO&output=json")

if c == 200 then
    -- Process the response
    results = json.decode(r)["ResultSet"]["Result"]
    -- Iterate over the results
    for i=1,table.getn(results) do
        print("Result "..i..":")
        table.foreach(results[i], print)
        print()
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks RBerteig....response from you and Lix helped a lot..I am right now stuck in stand alone implmentation of facebook connect api since all fb is asking me the url or app id to get me the the secret key and the id...anyways I will post my findings as and when I progress along

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I will start and say that I have no knowledge of Lua what-so-ever.  That said, any language with the capability of making http requests can use the facebook api.
[Facebook's documentation of the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) details what and where exactly to query.

As I imagined there are lots of resources on [Lua and networking](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=lua+http+requests). The actual calls to facebook look something like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
 client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
```

With that code you retrieve your access token, and then you can make requests like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/SOME_USER_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

That will give you a JSON response with the users wall and its data.

A GREAT place to start playing with those urls and their meanings is [this great tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) from facebook. Its the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). Click on `get access token` and mark the permissions you need and then poke away at all your facebook data!

Comment: Thanks Lix....response from you helped a lot..I am right now stuck in stand alone implmentation of facebook connect api since all fb is asking me the url or app id to get me the the secret key and the id...anyways I will post my findings as and when I progress along –